# Positioning datepicker button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am developing my website using ASP.Net and jQuery. I am using a month picker control. I would like to put the button next to the input to show the date. Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  @Html.TextBox("IconDemo", DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/yyyy"), new { @id = "IconDemo", @class = "Default form-control form-control-sm", @readonly = true })
</div>
```

```js
$("#IconDemo").MonthPicker({
  Button: "<button id='btmonthpicker' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' ><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></button>",
  Position: {
    collision: 'fit',
    at: 'left top',
    my: 'left bottom',
    of: $('#IconDemo')
  },
  format: "mm-yy",
  startView: "months",
  minViewMode: "months",
  MaxMonth: 0,
  MaxYear: 0,
});
```

[image]

Comment: This is normally how it works by default. Check that the containing element is wide enough to fit both the input and button on one line without causing a line break

Comment: @Nessserine ben guirat, I am not clear about your question. what you mean by 'I would like to put the button next to the input to show the date'. What you want to happen in the button click?. Do you want to display all days from 1 to 31

Comment: @Golda as the photo show i have a datepicker to choose the month and the year and show it in the input .  the orange button open the datepicker  i need the button to be in the right of the input

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not appear to be a jQuery UI DatePicker widget. You will need to expand the `div` so that it can contain the elements. The `fit` will move it if it does not fit. Also your `at` and `my` may need adjustment. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution for this problem

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="pull-right">
  @Html.TextBox("IconDemo", DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/yyyy"), new { @id = "IconDemo", @class = "Default form-control form-control-sm", @readonly = true })
</div>
</div>
```

it's just to add the class pull-right to the div that contain the datepicker